# Jquery - reading value from dynamic var?

Tags: jquery, variables

I've got this snippet of code..

```
var test_a = "<?php echo $a ?>"
console.log (test_a);
```

This shows `1.576.21422` which is correct.

But when I try the same here I don't get the result I was expecting.. I get the variable name.

I know in this test `fieldData[0] = 'a'`

```
    console.log ("test_" + fieldData[0])
```

Instead of showing 1.576.21422 I get `test_a`

Can someone point me in the right direction for this... Thanks

Comment: That may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26020014/2324107 . I actuallythink it's a duplicate but since my close vote equal an instant close and I am not sure, ill leave it open

Comment: http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/dynamic-variables-in-javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is you're outputting a string concatenated with another string. Your goal is to turn the resulting string into a variable. You could make the variable a member of a particular object (or the window object) and access the value of that member using  the notation `object[ "key" ]`.

[**Warning**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019658/) -- Even though `eval( .... )` would work, I would not advice you to use it.

This should work:

```
window.test_a = "<?php echo $a ?>";
//.....
console.log ( window[ "test_" + fieldData[0] ] );
```

To avoid cluttering the global scope, this would be the recommended way:

```
var myObject = { test_a: "<?php echo $a ?>" };
//.......
console.log ( myObject[ "test_" + fieldData[0] ] );
```