# Correct use of eval in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, eval

I want to load a different audio file clicking on different texts in a web page. I use the  following jQuery function:

```js
var audio = document.createElement('audio');      
$(".text_sample").on("click", function() {
  audio.src = eval(this.id);
  audio.play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="text_sample" id="a_music">music</a><br />
<a class="text_sample" id="a_weather">weather</a>
```

Do you think is correct to use `eval` in this context? Are better way to do it?

Comment: Huh? But what does `a_music` evaluate to?  This code should just throw an "Uncaught ReferenceError"

Comment: @JosephMarikle actually, if you have an element on the page with an id, browsers (maybe not all of them?) will add a variable to the window object. So window.a_music will be defined. Still not the right approach, but it won't throw an error unless you're in strict mode

Comment: @NicholasTower Ah!  Yes, you are right.  I completely forgot that was a thing.

Comment: Sorry, I closed as dup, but realized you asked for getting a variable while the other question was for setting a variable. Anyway, you might find interesting information from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019658/get-elements-id-and-set-it-as-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following if it is a global variable.

```
audio.src = window[this.id];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you explain me why this is better?

Comment: The reason is the `eval` is considered as a bad coding practice by most experts and it is not really required in you case.  `eval(this.id)` suggested that there was variables with names `a_music` and `a_weather`. All the global variables can be found inside the `window` object. So instead of `eval` we can simply use a `structure` reference for getting value.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that you have some variables that correspond to the IDs of the element and you want to use the element ID to get the value of the variable.

While `eval` works, I wouldn't do it. There's not much of a security issue,  as any eval'd code would only affect the user's own machine, but a cleaner approach would be to use `data-` attributes instead.

```
  <a class="text_sample" id="a_music" data-src="/foo.wav">music</a><br />
  <a class="text_sample" id="a_weather" data-src="/bar.wav">weather</a>
```

Then there's no need to rely on local variables at all. Instead use the `dataset` object on the element to get the `src`.

```
  var audio = document.createElement('audio');      
  $(".text_sample").on("click", function() {
      audio.src = this.dataset.src;
      audio.play();
  });
```

This also avoids killing optimizations as `eval` may do.