# Is it advisable to add to the global window object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So I'm working a React/Typescript project, where I need to store a value for the number of rows that needs to be accessible globally.

Is it a good idea to define it on the window object?

```
window.MySpace = {};
MySpace.rowCount = 10;
```

Are there any issues that could arise as the project grows? Or is there a more elegant way of handling this through Typescript?

Thanks!

edit:

Declare it as a module in a `module.ts` file

```
export module Global {
    export const rowCount = 10;
}
```

Then import it to whichever file requires the value of `rowCount`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing a variable in the JavaScript 'window' object is a proper way to use that object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393303/storing-a-variable-in-the-javascript-window-object-is-a-proper-way-to-use-that)

Answer (score 0):

> where I need to store a value for the number of rows that needs to be accessible globally

If you *have* to have to globally then ofcourse you would put it on `window`. The biggest concern would be naming `MySpace` conflict.

## Rethink

However you probably don't need it globally, and really you should use a module.

Comment: " The biggest concern would be naming MySpace conflict." - Could you elaborate?

Comment: If someone else decides to use the same name (called `MySpace`) you would have a naming conflict

Comment: I've updated the original post with a different approach. Would appreciate your input. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When You need to store a value that needs to be accessible globally, create a global object with a unique name, with your variables as properties of that object:

```
window.MySpace= {};
```

Then use it in whatever way you prefer.
Use it with functions

```
MySpace.show();
MySpace.hide();
```

Assign a value to it

```
MySpace.value=1;
MySpace.value=2;
```

different ways to handle that

```
MySpace.rowCount = 10;
```

and yes it is sometimes a good idea to define it on the window object, some cases require other ways of defining.

You're good to go!!