# Push same multiple objects into multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

This is a follow up to [Make 3 arrays correspond to each other with the first being the object name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57564488/make-3-arrays-correspond-to-each-other-with-the-first-being-the-object-name/57564570?noredirect=1#comment101594083_57564570).

AFter I create my objects:

```
let objName = ["object1", "object2", "object3"];
let xyzArr = ["xyz1", "xyz2","xyz3"];
let theArr = [[], [], []];

objName.forEach((name, index) => {
  window[name] = {
    xyz: xyzArr[index],
    arr: theArr[index]
  };
});
```

I use getJSON and want to use those values to push into the `array: arr[]`.  I have multiple objects that have the `arr[]` and I want to push values into all of them.

This is what I tried so far:

```
$.getJSON(json, result => 
    {result.forEach((elem, i, array) => 
       {object1.arr.push({x:elem.val1, y:elem.val2});
       {object2.arr.push({x:elem.val1, y:elem.val2});
       {object3.arr.push({x:elem.val1, y:elem.val2});
    }) 
 });
```

When I do this one by one, it works. No errors. Is there a way for me to push these same values into how many ever `object[i]` I have?

I tried:

```
 $.getJSON(json, result => 
    {result.forEach((elem, i, array) => 
       (for let j=0; j<=5; j++) {
           {object[i].arr.push({x:elem.val1, y:elem.val2});
       )       
    }) 
 });
```

When I do this I get `Cannot call method 'push' of undefined`.

Is there a way to do this without making my code long and bulky?

Comment: I'm surprised that `object1.data.push` works when `data` isn't defined on `object1` ?

Comment: That was my bad. Let me fix the code. I forgot to fix that when I typed it out here

Comment: Make a jsFiddle to demonstrate the problem. Would make it a thousand times easier to debug than the already buggy js you’re adapting from your real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of dynamically creating variables using `window`, you can use an array to store a collection of your objects like so:

```
let xyzArr = ["xyz1", "xyz2", "xyz3"];
let theArr = [[], [], []];
let objects = [];

objName.forEach((name, index) => {
  objects.push({
    xyz: xyzArr[index],
    arr: theArr[index]
  });
});
```

And then when adding data to each object, you can loop through it using a `.forEach()` on your `objects` array like so:

```
$.getJSON(json, result => {
  result.forEach(elem => {
    objects.forEach(obj => {
      obj.arr.push({
        x: elem.val1,
        y: elem.val2
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I dont want to use an array of objects. Is there anyways to use forEach with out the array?

Comment: @noob hey, is there a particular reason why you can't use arrays? Arrays are the perfect thing to use for cases like these

Answer (score 2):

`object[i]` refers to an array named `object` which obviously doesn't exist.

Try this oneliner instead:

```
$.getJSON(json, result => result.forEach((elem, i, array) => window['object' + (i + 1)].data.push({ x: elem.val1, y: elem.val2 })));
```

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` error

Comment: then your `result` has a greater length than the existing objects?

Comment: pretty sure you would need to use `window['object' + i+1]`

Comment: I think the value of `i` could exceed `3` though. You'd most likely need an inner for-loop to loop through all the object variables