# Push same multiple objects into multiple arrays based on another value from object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

This is a follow up to again  [Push same multiple objects into multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57571725/push-same-multiple-objects-into-multiple-arrays).

AFter I create my objects:

```
let objName = ["object1", "object2", "object3"];
let xyzArr = ["xyz1", "xyz2", "xyz3"];
let theArr = [[], [], []];
let objects = [];

objName.forEach((name, index) => {
  objects.push({
    xyz: xyzArr[index],
    arr: theArr[index]
 });
});
```

And push values using @NickParsons solution:

```
$.getJSON(json, result => {
  result.forEach(elem => {
   objects.forEach(obj => {
     obj.arr.push({
       x: elem.date,
       y: elem.val2
     });
   });
  });
 });
```

Here I am adding my objects, i.e. x and y based on no condition. But I want to add it based on `if indexOf(obj.xyz) = elem.val1`.

THis is my JSON:

```
  [
{
    "date": "2019-07-21",
    "val1": "xyz1_hello",
    "val2": 803310
},
{
    "date": "2019-07-22",
    "val1": "xyz2_yellow",
    "val2": 23418
},
{
    "date": "2019-07-22",
    "val1": "xyz1_hello",
    "val2": 6630
},
{
    "date": "2019-07-24",
    "val1": "xyz2_yellow",
    "val2": 4
},
{
    "date": "2019-07-21",
    "val1": "xyz3_yo",
    "val2": 60984
}
]
```

Is there a way for me to push values to `x and y` if `obj.xyz is LIKE (indexOF) elem.val1` For example, `if indexOf(obj.xyz) = elem.val1`, then push their corresponding `elem.date` and `elem.val2` data to `obj.arr`.

Comment: Your explanation is a little hard to follow. Maybe add examples from source a/b and the desired output?

Comment: I made some changes. I tried to explain the best I could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some boolean `like(a,b)` function that decides if two values are similar or not, and your elements are in `elems`:

```
objects.forEach(o => 
  elems.forEach(e => {
    if(like(o.xyz, e.val1)){
      o.arr.push({
        x: e.date,
        y: e.val2
      });
    }
  }));
```