# Send data across two pages using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am a .NET stack developer and I am not so strong in JavaScript. I want to pass a variable defined in the script tag of one html page and retrieve it in a different page. By the time execution control gets to the second page, the value assigned to the variable has been lost and subsequently `testVar` is null. I'm trying to achieve something similar to this:

In C# I would define a static global variable to achieve this.

HTML Page 1:

```
<script>
var someVariable = "Hello Word";
</script>
```

HTML Page 2:

```
<script>
var testVar = someVariable;
//Expecting testVar to be assigned with Hello World
</script>
```

Comment: You can't pass variables this way. If on the same domain you can leverage localStorage, but that smells kinda strange. What are you attempting to do exactly in the context of a "real" example?

Comment: I am getting the current url assigned into `someVariable`. I want to take that and assigned it to `testVar` which will be used in an anchor tag defined in page 2 i.e Page 2 HTML will have <a href="tesVar"></a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store your variable in the global `window` object.

```
var someVariable = "Hello Word";

window.stored_value = someVariable;
```

The `window` object is global, so just use it in another script.

HTML Page 2:

```
<script>

var testVar = window.stored_value;

</script>
```

Please have a look at a similar issue:

[Storing a variable in the JavaScript 'window' object is a proper way to use that object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393303/storing-a-variable-in-the-javascript-window-object-is-a-proper-way-to-use-that)

Comment: Then how will I access it in HTML Page 2?

Comment: I made use of localStorage on the window object

Comment: Keep in mind that localStorage supports only string format and returns a value as a string 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage

Answer (score 0):

You'll most likely need to look into the [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), but without knowing more about the two windows and how they are related to each other (was one opened by clicking on a link in the first, for example) it's hard to give you more direction.

Answer (score 0):

Inother to access external javascript in your html file, create a separate `.js` file e.g `script.js` and define `someVariable` in it then add the script to both html files via the script tag as so `<script src="script.js"></script>`.

In the `script.js` file add the code:

```js
var someVariable = "Hello Word";
```

Comment: Then how will I access it in HTML Page 2?

Comment: @Harold_Finch the same way you already are, 

`<script>
var testVar = someVariable;
</script>
`
but this time testVar will be defined